# Deriving the midpoint formula in 3D using the distance formula

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I want to derive the midpoint of the line segment connecting the points $P_1(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $P_2(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ using only the distance formula (since this is all that has been taught to students thus far; if more is needed, please let me know.)

I began by characterizing the midpoint as the point $M(x,y,z)$ such that $|P_1M|=|P_2M|$ which is equivalent to $$(x_1-x)^2+(y_1-y)^2+(z_1-z)^2=(x_2-x)^2+(y_2-y)^2+(z_2-z)^2$$

after squaring both sides. Expanding and cancelling the identical terms from both sides leaves us: $$x_1^2-2x_1x+y_1^2-2y_1y+z_1^2-2z_1z=x_2^2-2x_2x+y_2^2-2y_2y+z_2^2-2z_2z$$

which is equivalent to, after rearranging: $$(x_1^2-x_2^2)+(y_1^2-y_2^2)+(z_1^2-z_2^2)=2x_1x-2x_2x+2y_1y-2y_2y+2z_1z-2z_2z$$

or $$(x_1+x_2)(x_1-x_2)+(y_1+y_2)(y_1-y_2)+(z_1+z_2)(z_1-z_2)=2[x(x_1-x_2)+y(y_1-y_2)+z(z_1-z_2)]$$

Now divide by $2$ on both sides $$\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right)(x_1-x_2)+\left(\frac{y_1+y_2}{2}\right)(y_1-y_2)+\left(\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}\right)(z_1-z_2)=x(x_1-x_2)+y(y_1-y_2)+z(z_1-z_2)$$

and subtract all the terms on the right from both sides: $$(x_1-x_2)\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}-x\right)+(y_1-y_2)\left(\frac{y_1+y_2}{2}-y\right)+(z_1-z_2)\left(\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}-z\right)=0$$

Since $(x_1-x_2), (y_1-y_2),$ and $(z_1-z_2)$ are not all necessarily simultaneously zero, we must have that: $$\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}-x=0,\frac{y_1+y_2}{2}-y=0, \frac{z_1+z_2}{2}-z=0 $$ or $$x=\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$$ $$y=\frac{y_1+y_2}{2}$$ $$z=\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}$$

This $M=\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2},\frac{y_1+y_2}{2},\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}\right)$ turns out to be the midpoint formula for the line segment connecting the points $P_1(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $P_2(x_2,y_2,z_2)$, but I realized that the original assumption that $|P_1M|=|P_2M|$ is not sufficient to characterize the midpoint of a line segment, although necessary.

For example, one could put points $P_1$ and $P_2$ at the vertices of the base of an isosceles  triangle and point $M$ at the remaining vertex so that $|P_1M|=|P_2M|$, but in this case clearly $M$ isn't the midpoint of the line segment connecting $P_1$ and $P_2$ since it isn't even on this line segment!

So my question is: why was I able to derive the midpoint formula from the necessary but not sufficient condition that $|P_1M|=|P_2M|$?

**Edit:** All of the above is wrong based on the false assumption I made, pointed out by @Blue in the comments.

I am still trying to prove this midpoint formula using the distance formula, barring vector/line methods from sections ahead.

Comment: Btw, I would have done this problem by writing down the equation of the line segment between the two points and plugging in $t=1/2$ but students have not learned that material yet :( Also this section comes before vectors...

Comment: *"Since $(x_1−x_2)$, $(y_1−y_2)$, and $(z_1−z_2)$ are not all necessarily simultaneously zero, we must have that: ..."* Well, no. More simply, you have $$ap+bq+cr=0$$ where $a$, $b$, $c$ are not all zero, and you're concluding that $p$, $q$, $r$ *must* all be zero. But taking, eg, $a=b=c=1$, $p=1$, $q=1$, $r=-2$ shows that the conclusion is false. ... Your students may not know vectors, but since you presumably do: You've asserting that vectors $(a,b,c)$ and $(p,q,r)$ have a zero dot product *only if* one of them is all-zero, when in fact non-zero vectors that are *orthogonal* will do.

Comment: Yikes...I did conclude that @Blue, thank you. Do you have any tips on how to prove this midpoint formula using only the distance formula?

Comment: Replace the condition $|P_1M|=|P_2M|$ with the dual conditions $2|P_1M|=|P_1P_2|$ and $2|P_2M|=|P_1P_2|$. These allow you to write $2|P_1M|^2+2|P_2M|^2=|P_1P_2|^2$ which you can finagle into the relation $$(2x-x_1-x_2)^2+(2y-y_1-y_2)^2+(2z-z_1-z_2)^2=0$$ Here, it's perfectly safe to conclude that a sum of squares (of reals) is zero only if each individual term is zero, giving the result. ... The algebra is a bit of a slog, and the grouping into squares a bit "clever". I might suggest warming-up the class w/the same argument in $2$d (or even $1$d), where it may be easier to spot the groupings.)

Comment: Thank you very much @Blue! I basically expounded upon your work here in an answer below. The factorization hint is definitely what I needed.

Comment: BTW: The algebraic approach w/the distance formula is a nice character-building exercise in symbol crunching, but a *better* approach is geometric. Use triangles to show that the midpt of the "body diagonal" of an axis-aligned shoebox projects to mdpts of the box's edges; those edge-mdpts are "obviously" averages of the respective edge-endpts, and the result follows. Students presumably used the shoebox to derive the distance formula in the first place, so it's not unfamiliar. And, this shows that geometric thinking still matters after Geometry class. Moreover, it anticipates vector methods.

Answer (score 1):

Going on @Blue's advice, if $M(x,y,z)$ is the midpoint of $P_1$ and $P_2$, then $2|P_1M|=|P_1P_2|$ and $2|P_2M|=|P_1P_2|$.

These two conditions ensure $M$ is both halfway between $P_1$ and $P_2$ and that $M$ is actually on the line segment connecting $P_1$ and $P_2$ (for if not, $M$ must be on two disjoint spheres, except for one point, both of radius $\frac{1}{2}|P_1P_2|$; but this is impossible so $M$ is the single point of intersection between the two spheres on the line segment connecting $P_1$ and $P_2$).

Since $2|P_1M|=|P_1P_2|$ and $2|P_2M|=|P_1P_2|$, we have $2|P_1M|^2+2|P_2M|^2=|P_1P_2|^2$ after squaring both equations and adding them together, which is equivalent to: $$2[(x_1-x)^2+(y_1-y)^2+(z_1-z)^2]+2[(x_2-x)^2+(y_2-y)^2+(z_2-z)^2]=(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2+(z_1-z_2)^2$$ $\iff$ $$x_1^2-4x_1x+2x^2+y_1^2-4y_1y+2y^2+z_1^2-4z_1z+2z^2+x_2^2-4x_2x+2x^2+y_2^2-4y_2y+2y^2+z_2^2-4z_2z+2z^2+2x_1x_2+2y_1y_2+2z_1z_2=0$$

$\iff$ $$(4x^2+x_1^2+x_2^2-4x_1x+2x_1x_2-4x_2x)+(4y^2+y_1^2+y_2^2-4y_1y+2y_1y_2-4y_2y)+(4z^2+z_1^2+z_2^2-4z_1z+2z_1z_2-4z_2z)=0$$

$\iff \text{since $(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ac$}$

$$(2x-x_1-x_2)^2+(2y-y_1-y_2)^2+(2z-z_1-z_2)^2=0$$

Finally, for a sum of squares to be zero, each term being squared must be zero $\therefore$ $$2x-x_1-x_2=0\iff x= \frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$$ $$2y-y_1-y_2=0\iff y= \frac{y_1+y_2}{2}$$ $$2z-z_1-z_2=0\iff z= \frac{z_1+z_2}{2}$$

Thus, we've shown the midpoint $M=\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2},\frac{y_1+y_2}{2},\frac{z_1+z_2}{2}\right)$.

Comment: +1. Minor notes: "The" reason $M$ is on the line is the (degenerate) Triangle Inequality: $|P_1M|+|P_2M|=|P_1P_2|$ implies the pts form a "flat" triangle; ie, they're collinear. Also, since the work happens coord-wise, I'd write-out only the $x$-stuff, to reduce clutter; eg, $$\begin{align}
&2[(x-x_1)^2+\cdots y,z\cdots]\\
+&2[(x-x_2)^2+\cdots y,z\cdots]\\ 
=&\phantom{2}(x_1-x_2)^2 +\cdots y,z\cdots\\
\iff&x_1^2-4x_1x+2x^2-4x_2x+2x^2+2x_1x_2&&+\cdots y,z\cdots=0\\
\iff&4x^2-4x(x_1+x_2)+(x_1+x_2)^2&&+\cdots y,z \cdots=0\\
\iff&(2x-(x_1+x_2))^2&&+\cdots y,z\cdots=0
\end{align}$$